# Display Column Chart Y Axis Labels in Kilo(K), Million(M) in webi reports

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Can we do formatting in Column chart value Axis Labels to show $1000000 as $1M, that is to replace 0's with M for million representation in Webi Reports?

Please guide me if this is possible.

Thanks

Niki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't tell Web Intelligence to automatically change 1.000.000 to 1M and 1.000 to 1K, there is another approach which may meet your needs halfway.

In an existing chart, right-click on the category axis and select *Format Chart Value* from the popup menu.

[image: Format Chart Value]

Next, look for the setting *Unit Scale Factor*. By default this is set to `0`. Change it to the number of 0's you want to remove from the values. Thus, set it to 3 if you want to change 5.000 to 5.

[image: Unit scale factor]

Additionally, you could indicate the scale that was set in the title of the value axis.

Comment: Thanks Kristof. Thats a good idea. So what you mean is to do the changes in Unit Factor Scale and in the Value Axis Title just to add like "In Millions". Hope what i understood is correct?